# How to convert a .csv file to shapefile with the attribute table geometry using pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis, csv

I am trying to convert a .csv file to .shp using pyqgis. With this publication ETA managed to generate the file with all its extensions and the table of attributes but I do not see the entities (type point). column 1 and 2 have the information of Lat and Long the code I have is this:

```
ruta = "C:/Users/Pc/Desktop/MANUELITA/productividad/CSV/35300030000_C58_b.csv" # set the filepath for the input CSV
inp_tab = QgsVectorLayer(ruta, 'Input_Table', 'ogr')
salida = 'C:/Users/Pc/Desktop/MANUELITA/productividad/CSV/prueba.shp'
fields = inp_tab.fields()
crs = 4326 
outLayer=QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(inp_tab, salida,"fields" ,inp_tab.crs() ,"ESRI Shapefile", layerOptions=['SHPT=POINT'])
```

the .csv fields looks like this:
[image]

Comment: With your approach,  you also need to set the geometry of each point to a feature. However, in my **Editing Note** there is another approximation by using an uri (uniform resource identifier) with delimiters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, you also need to set the geometry of each point to a feature; as in following script:

```
ruta = '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/temp_max.csv' # set the filepath for the input CSV

lon_field = 'x' # set the name for the field containing the longitude
lat_field = 'y' # set the name for the field containing the latitude

crs = 4326 # set the crs as needed

salida = '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/temp_max.shp' # set the filepath for the output shapefile

spatRef = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(crs, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId)

inp_tab = QgsVectorLayer(ruta, 'Input_Table', 'ogr')
fields = inp_tab.fields()

outLayer = QgsVectorFileWriter(salida, 
                               None, 
                               fields, 
                               QgsWkbTypes.Point, 
                               spatRef,
                               "ESRI Shapefile")

pt = QgsPointXY()
outFeature = QgsFeature()

for feat in inp_tab.getFeatures():
    attrs = feat.attributes()
    pt.setX(float(feat[lon_field]))
    pt.setY(float(feat[lat_field]))
    outFeature.setAttributes(attrs)
    outFeature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(pt))
    outLayer.addFeature(outFeature)

del outLayer
```

I used a CVS file with many fields as in your case. After running above script in Python Console of QGIS 3.12, I got result of following image:

[image]

**Editing Note:**

Based in [QGIS documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html), I also found the following solution:

```
uri = "file:///home/zeito/pyqgis_data/temp_max.csv?delimiter={}&xField={}&yField={}".format(",", "x", "y")
inp_tab = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 
                         "temp_max", 
                         "delimitedtext")

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(inp_tab)

salida = '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/temp_max4.shp' # set the filepath for the output shapefile

crs = 4326 # set the crs as needed

spatRef = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(crs, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId)

outLayer=QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(inp_tab, 
                                                 salida,
                                                 'UTF-8',
                                                 spatRef,
                                                 "ESRI Shapefile")
```

After running above script, result is totally equivalent to above image.